# Calculating midpoint between every two closest points using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, angles

I am looking to try and identify the midpoint between two closest points in my layer in ArcGIS Pro.

The reason being that I work in the utilities industry and I am trying to calculate the angle between every structure in the network. Using the Near tool I was able to calculate it, but there are instances where structures are side by side. For this instance I would look at the two very close structures as one structure for the purpose of finding the angle in between. The structures side by side give me an angle of 0, 90 or 180 when calculating the angle via the near tool.

I have subsetted them to only focus on those "problem structures" and tried things such as aggregating points, buffering and intersection etc but am now stuck.

Comment: Could you give some example of what your data looks like? Is there a separate line layer connecting your points? And can you give some example of the expected output?

Comment: If you are considering two close structures as one area and thus do not want to calculate the angle between them, I would just buffer all points by half the distance you consider close (i.e. if structure within 500m of each other are 'close' then use a 250m buffer). When buffering, there should be an option to combine overlapping polygons. Then from this polygon layer, create a new point layer from the centroids. This should keep all 'stand alone' structures as they were and combine 'close' structures to single points now